# Latest possible entry after getting an Australian working holiday visa

Tags: visas, australia, working-holiday

Let's say you apply for an Australian working holiday visa one day before your 31st birthday and get it (as a German citizen), how much time do you have to travel to Australia and officially start your working holiday stay?

I assume here that the visa days start counting from the day of entry to Australia. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest you can enter Australia is 12 months after the working holiday visa was granted.

From the [Department of Home Affairs](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/work-holiday-417/first-working-holiday-417#When) web site:

> ## How long you can stay
>
> This is a temporary visa. You must enter Australia within 12 months of
>   the date we grant it.
>
> The visa becomes active on the date you enter Australia. Once you have
>   entered and the visa is activated, you can:
>
> - stay in Australia for up to 12 months
> - leave and re-enter Australia as many times as you like in that 12 months
>
> To see when you must leave, use [VEVO](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/already-have-a-visa/check-visa-details-and-conditions/overview).